# Cython: How do I wrap a C++ class where public member variables are custom objects?

Tags: c++, cython

## Problem:

To illustrate, I'll use the [simple Rectangle tutorial in the Cython docs](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#an-example-c-api). Suppose I add a custom c++ object `Coord`:

```
//Rectangle.h
class Coord {
public:
    int x, y;
    Coord(int x0, int y0);
    ~Coord();
    void move(int dx, int dy);

    //Omitted the rest for brevity...
};
```

And I make two public member variables in `Rectangle` to represent the lower left and upper right corners of the rectangle:

```
//Rectangle.h
class Rectangle {
public:
    Coord lower_left, upper_right;          //added this

    //Omitted the rest for brevity...
};
```

If I want to manipulate the `Coord`s in Python as python objects, how would I do this? This seems like such a basic thing to do, but I haven't found any tutorials/guides online that illustrate how to do this.

---

## What I tried:

So in my attempt, I tried wrapping the `Coord`s as `PyCoord` in order for `PyRectangle` to mirror the c++ rectangle object. In the definitions, I exposed the c++ `Coord` and added them as member variables of `Rectangle` like this:

```
#rect.pyx
cdef cppclass Coord:                        #added this cppclass
    Coord(int, int) except +
    void move(int, int)

cdef cppclass Rectangle:
    Rectangle(int, int, int, int) except +
    Coord lower_left, upper_right           #added these member variables

#The rest omitted for brevity...
```

And here's what I tried doing in the wrappers:

```
#rect.pyx
cdef class PyCoord:
    cdef Coord *thisptr

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.thisptr = new Coord(0,0)
    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr
    def move(self, int dx, int dy):
        self.thisptr.move(dx, dy)

cdef class PyRectangle:
    cdef Rectangle *thisptr
    cdef PyCoord lower_left, upper_right    #want to manipulate these in Python

    def __cinit__(self, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1):
        self.thisptr = new Rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1)
        self.lower_left.thisptr = &(self.thisptr.lower_left)
        self.upper_right.thisptr = &(self.thisptr.upper_right)

#The rest omitted for brevity...
```

So the first concern with the above is that there is a memory leak when I reassign the `lower_left` and `upper_right` because the `new Coord(0,0)` was never deleted, right? But the main idea is to be able to do something like this from Python:

#### Python Interpreter

```
>>> from rect import *
>>> a = PyRectangle(1,1,2,2)
>>> a.upper_right.move(1,1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'move'
```

But as you can see, I'm running into problems. What's the best way to achieve this? There must be some standard way to do this, right?

---

**Edit:** So it looks like I can gain access to c++ member variables that are primitives like this:

```
#rect.pyx
cdef cppclass Coord:
    int x, y                                #exposed x and y to cython
    Coord(int, int) except +
    void move(int, int)

cdef class PyCoord:
    cdef Coord *thisptr

    property c_x:                   #can use this to access C++ member x
        def __get__(self):
            return self.thisptr.x
        def __set__(self, int i):
            self.thisptr.x = i

    property c_y:                   #can use this to access C++ member y
        def __get__(self):
            return self.thisptr.y
        def __set__(self, int i):
            self.thisptr.y = i

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.thisptr = new Coord(0,0)
    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr
    def move(self, int dx, int dy):
        self.thisptr.move(dx, dy)
```

As a result, I can do this in the interpreter:

#### Python Interpreter

```
>>> from rect import *
>>> a = PyCoord()
>>> a.c_x = 1
>>> a.c_y = 2
>>> print ("(%s, %s)"%(a.c_x, a.c_y))
(1, 2)
```

But still no luck with custom object types. I can't use `property` to get/set `Coord` in `PyRectangle`, or at least don't know how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a way of wrapping a `Coord` that doesn't claim ownership of the memory. The following modification of `PyCoord` holds a reference to the actual owner, both to indicate that the `PyCoord` shouldn't free the memory, and to keep the actual owner alive as long as the `PyCoord` is alive.

```
cdef class PyCoord:
    cdef Coord *thisptr
    cdef object owner # None if this is our own

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.thisptr = new Coord(0,0)
        owner = None
    cdef set_ptr(self,Coord* ptr,owner):
        if self.owner is None:
            del self.thisptr
        self.thisptr = ptr
        self.owner = owner
    def __dealloc__(self):
        # only free if we own it
        if self.owner is None:
            del self.thisptr
    def move(self, int dx, int dy):
        self.thisptr.move(dx, dy)
```

You can use properties to provide a nice interface for `PyRectangle`

```
cdef class PyRectangle:
    cdef Rectangle *thisptr

    def __cinit__(self, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1):
        self.thisptr = new Rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1)

    property lower_left:
        def __get__(self):
            c = PyCoord()
            # for some reason I couldn't do two levels of pointer access at once...
            # so we use a temporary
            thisptr = self.thisptr
            c.set_ptr(&thisptr.lower_left,self)
            return c
    # lower_right looks identical
```

*Note*: Handling lots of different cases of object ownership is certainly something that Boost Python has thought about (and I think something that SWIG has thought about too) so if you're going a lot of this they may provide a slightly more elegant solution.

Comment: Thanks again DavidW! I owe you a drink.